# ruby or rails error: incompatible library version -- parser.bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run my ruby script, but I keep getting this error.  I've tried reinstalling ruby and rails.  ruby version is 2.3.3 and rails is 4.2.5.  any ideas?

> > ruby firebasepushserver.rb

```
/Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:7:in `<module:Ext>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:6:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json.rb:59:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json.rb:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg/text_encoder.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:63:in `<module:PG>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/paulyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
    from firebasepushserver.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the gem? `gem uninstall json; bundle install`? I had the same issue and just removing all versions and installing them again worked for me.

Comment: ah ok, let me try that.

Comment: @frbl That worked for me, thanks!

Comment: I've been getting these all the time. Super annoying. `gem pristine --all` fixes it.